# How to unit test a flow with async down the line

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a flow that starts with a regular function (no async in method signature) and down the line I call Task.Run(await () => asyncFunction()).

Aside from it being bad practice to do await and not expect anything back, is there a way i can run a unit test that will run the code to the end?
Currently, once the unit test finishes, the task that needs to run in the Task.Run gets cancelled since the task is async and gets put at the end of the task queue (as far as i understand), the main thread finishes and the task doesnt get a chance to run.

Thanks

EDIT : adding MVP :

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Foo()
        {
            Task.Run(async () => await AsyncMethod());
        }

        private async Task AsyncMethod()
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("Waited 3 seconds");
        }
    }
}
```

And unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Debug2()
{
    var c = new Class1();
    c.Foo();
}
```

I would like the write line to execute

Thanks

Comment: Does the async function alter any state? Can you check that state? Wait in your test until the state change was observed (busy waiting, thread.sleep, …)

Comment: @knittl That's a good idea but unfortunately the async function does a void non-state changing (as in pure function) logic.

Comment: @MickyD edited and added example with code

Comment: thank-you for update

Comment: @Ace66 if it doesn't have any side effects (i.e. is pure) and you are not observing its return value, then it is not doing anything useful (the program would be equivalent if it didn't run at all).

Comment: @knittl it is writing logs. I meant no side effects as in not changing objects that are in the code

Comment: @Ace66 writing logs is a side-effect (and a very big one at that). Either inject a custom logger which can be observed from your code (~unit test) or wait for the log file to contain the logs you expect (~integration test).

Comment: @knittl The thing is, the side effect of writing log doesn't happen because the main thread exists before the async method has a chance to run. I added an example, to make it clearer.

Comment: @Ace66 and my initial advice still stands: block the main thread until you have observed your side effect. Be it busy waiting (`while (!logFile.contains("expected));`), "estimated" sleeping (`Thread.sleep(5000); Assert.That(logFile…)`) or something more elaborate (for example injecting a custom logger with waithandles). If a side-effect is important, make it observable. If it cannot be observed, restructure your code to make it so.

Comment: @Ace66 [cont'd] … You write yourself "Aside from it being bad practice" – now you know _why_ it is considered bad practice: it makes your code hard to test ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Aside from it being bad practice to do await and not expect anything back, is there a way i can run a unit test that will run the code to the end?

One of the *reasons* "fire and forget" is a bad practice is that the calling code cannot know when the work is complete (or whether it completes, or if it completes with an error).

It is this very same reason that makes testing this difficult. You'll need to inject some kind of mock to detect whatever side-effects the work has, and busy-wait in your test until the side effect is observed. A timeout will be necessary to allow the test to fail (rather than hang), and timeouts make your tests inherently flakey. This is one reason why fire-and-forget is a bad practice.

Comment: Just found this question and @stephen-cleary 's answer. Fire-and-forget might be a bad practice, but it something inevitable in some cases, eg. in any code that uses channels. Even the simplest implementation of a pub-sub broker will give you a fire-and-forget `Publish` method that you can't really test without doing some sort of busy-waiting on the subscriber side. I've spent months trying to figure out a robust way to test this kind of code, and I still have lots of flaky tests.

Comment: @MártonBalassa: I use channels without fire-and-forget. You do end up with `Task` objects that represent your producers and consumers, which can then be `await`ed. You may also find my (experimental) [structured concurrency library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/StructuredConcurrency) useful.